# How can I flatten, combine, or trace non-overlapping shapes in Sketch?

Tags: vector, sketch-app

Currently stuck in Sketch hell. I have a bunch of combined shapes made of non-overlapping triangles. I need them to behave like single, solid shapes so I can apply a border to them. Currently, when I apply a border it outlines every single triangle inside the combined shape.

To create the larger shape, I select a few triangles and press "union", which creates a combined shape group. I tried flattening that, which resulted in this error: "Can't flatten into a single shape. The shape you are trying to flatten requires more than one subpath to be rendered." I understand why this error pops up, but how do I make them one solid shape? I tried adding an additional shape that would overlap the triangles just so I can flatten and combine them, but this shape starts to subtract from them even though the mode is still "union" (see second picture).

Tracing the shape would be more work, but would solve the problem. I tried using the pen tool to click each corner to re-create the shape, but this doesn't snap to each point precisely. I need the points to be precisely aligned on this triangular grid.

[image: Picture of the current combined shape problem. You can see that the purple border outlines all triangles.]

[image: Picture of the bug that happens when I add an overlapping shape to the combined shape group]